# How can I get a shortest path on OpenStreetMap?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, shortest-path, osmnx

I've been working on finding shortest paths on OpenStreetMap. But some parts of the routes do not match the actual roads. As shown in the picture. [The routes do not match the actual roads.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aygJy.jpg)Is there any way to fix this problem? Also, here are the codes:

```
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
import folium

lat = [-33.889606, -33.889927, -33.889155, -33.891134]
lon = [151.283306, 151.280497, 151.278007, 151.274453]

fmap = folium.Map(location=[-33.889606, 151.283306], zoom_start=15)
colors=["red", "yellow", "green"]

for i in range(3):
    G = ox.graph_from_point((-33.889606, 151.283306), distance=4000,network_type='drive')
    a = ox.get_nearest_node(G, (lat[i], lon[i]))
    b = ox.get_nearest_node(G, (lat[i+1], lon[i+1]))
    route = nx.shortest_path(G, a, b)
    gdf_nodes, gdf_edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G)
    latitude = gdf_nodes.loc[route].y
    longitude = gdf_nodes.loc[route].x

    latitude = latitude.values
    longitude = longitude.values

    latitude=latitude.tolist()
    longitude=longitude.tolist()

    coordinate=[]
    for j in range(len(latitude)):
        coordinate.append([latitude[j],longitude[j]])
    fmap.add_child(folium.PolyLine(locations=coordinate, weight=5, color=colors[i]))

fmap
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with [OSMnx](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.folium). The following code snippet visualizes the route with folium while maintaining the curved street geometries:

```py
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(use_cache=True, log_console=True)

# get a graph
G = ox.graph_from_place('Piedmont, California, USA', network_type='drive')

# impute missing edge speed and add travel times
G = ox.add_edge_speeds(G)
G = ox.add_edge_travel_times(G)

# calculate shortest path minimizing travel time
orig, dest = list(G)[0], list(G)[-1]
route = nx.shortest_path(G, orig, dest, 'travel_time')

# create folium web map
route_map = ox.plot_route_folium(G, route)
route_map
```

[image]